# How to make link_to and custom URL work together on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I have a custom vanity URL setup, ala GitHub:

```
http://foo.com/:user/:stuff
```

I have routes to handle this as well:

```
match '/:user/:stuff', to: 'stuffs#show'
```

How can I make `link_to` work with this route for `stuff`?

```
link_to @stuff.name, @stuff
```

Comment: Have you read [the rails guide on routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)?

Comment: The most important part, overriding `to_param`, is missing. You don't have to do any of the above stuff to your routes.rb, just fix your `to_param` and your controller.

Comment: @meagar I don't follow regarding the `to_param`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make it through a route alias:

```
match '/:user/:stuff' => 'stuffs#show', :as => 'users_stuff'
```

And in your view call it normally, passing the two parameters:

```
<%= link_to 'Show', users_stuff_path(current_user,3) %>
```

Comment: This worked great, just had to overwrite `to_param` to use the `name` instead of the ID